# Access VBA - Displaying info form that user provided on another form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database with a (modal) login form where an employee enters their Username and Password.  After they log in, they will see another form, UserDashboard.  I want to be able to have their First and Last name appear on the UserDashboard, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I'm using a DLookup on the Login form to find the employee's first and last name from the Employees table (where their username and password are also stored).  Then I'm trying to display these variables on the UserDashboard, but since it's a separate form, there is nothing in the variables "First" and "Last" when UserDashboard loads.

Is there something I can do to place the First Name and Last Name on UserDashboard?

Code in the Login form:

```
First = DLookup("EmpFirstName", "Employees", "Username = '" & Me.txtUsername.Value & "'")
Last = DLookup("EmpLastName", "Employees", "Username = '" & Me.txtUsername.Value & "'")
```

Code for the UserDashboard form:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Me.txtDashboard = "User Dashboard - " & First & " " & Last

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variables outside the form in a module and use  them as global variables.

```
Public First As String
Public Last As String
```

Comment: Barry, thanks for the quick answer.  I defined the variables in a module, but when I tested, it still doesn't work.  Do I need to add anything else to the module or the Login or UserDashboard to have it work?

Comment: @user3507530 Sorry about that, you have to define them public

Comment: It isn't a bad idea (design wise) to define all your global variables in a module which is kept only for that purpose.